# SQL: building a filter - can this be done without dynamic sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, filter, dynamic-sql

This is what i see all the time in a list made by us.
Have to make a filter for 2 columns (i took a shorter example, we have lists with 50 columns, looks the same...)

I was wondering if there's a way to do this somehow different.
What do you guys use to filter records from a table?

```
    /* parameters */
@CostNumber = ...
@Description = ...
    /* parameters */

SET @strSQL = '
SELECT  [CostLevelId], [CostNumber], [Description]
FROM    [CostLevel]
WHERE   1 = 1 ' /* this looks weird, but we'll add the "WHERE" stuff easier */

IF (@CostNumber IS NOT NULL)
BEGIN
    SET @strSQL = @strSQL + ' AND [CostNumber] LIKE ''%' + REPLACE(@CostNumber,'''','''''') + '%'' '
END

IF (@Description IS NOT NULL)
BEGIN
    SET @strSQL = @strSQL + ' AND [Description] LIKE ''%' + REPLACE(@Description,'''','''''') + '%'' '
END

EXEC (@strSQL)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not scrap the dynamic SQL approach?

```
    /* parameters */
@CostNumber = ...
@Description = ...
    /* parameters */

SELECT  [CostLevelId], [CostNumber], [Description]
FROM    [CostLevel]
WHERE   [CostNumber] LIKE '%' + @CostNumber + '%'
AND [Description] LIKE '%' + @Description + '%'
```

Couple things to watch out for - `null`s in the `@CostNumber` and `@Description` params - you'll have to make sure you convert them to empty strings.

Another thing you'll need to consider is the fact that `@Description might` contain a `%` character, and you'll have to escape that for the `LIKE` to work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to do it when the `LIKE` operator is involved, when using comparison operators I'm using default values to obtain something like this:

```
select *
from dbo.SomeTable a
where
(a.IntColumn = @IntColumnValue or @IntColumnValue = -1)
and (a.VarCharColumn = @VarCharValue or @VarCharValue = 'zzz')
```

This way, if I don't want to apply a particular filter I just set it to the default value (in this example `-1` or `zzz`), so its check always yelds true.

Using the `LIKE` operator should be something similar, maybe you should set the default value to some sort of string you know will never be found in your data? Something like this?

```
where (a.VarCharColumn like '%' + @VarCharValue + '%' or @VarCharValue = '§§§TheDefaultValue§§§')
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a way to test this atm, but how about

```
SELECT  [CostLevelId], [CostNumber], [Description]
FROM [CostLevel]
WHERE (@CostNumber IS NOT NULL AND [CostNumber] LIKE ''%' + REPLACE(@CostNumber,'''','''''') + '%'')
OR
(@Description IS NOT NULL AND [Description] LIKE ''%' + REPLACE(@Description,'''','''''') + '%'')
GROUP BY [CostLevelId], [CostNumber], [Description]
```

Failing that, you could try a UNION instead of OR (and grouping).

Answer (score 0):

You can test to see if the value is null in the query, coupled with your condition and an or statement this allows for optional parameters.

This would work for a like statement.

```
SELECT  [CostLevelId], [CostNumber], [Description]
FROM    [CostLevel]
WHERE   
    (@CostNumber is null or [CostNumber] LIKE '%'+@CostNumber+'%')
    and
    (@Description is null or [Description] LIKE '%'+@Description+'%')
```

if its a straight equality comparison you can use coalesce to compare to either the populated variable or, when the variable is null, itself.

```
SELECT  [CostLevelId], [CostNumber], [Description]
FROM    [CostLevel]
WHERE   
    [CostNumber] = coalesce(@CostNumber,[CostNumber])
    and
    [Description] = coalesce(@Description,[CostNumber])
```

Keep in mind that this may have an adverse effect on your query plans dependant on which variables are set, table population and database structure etc.  You may even find that the dynamic sql approach executes more efficiently than this despite the additional complication in its construction.